# error converting int and add it to line function in opencv with python

Tags: python, opencv, line

I printed type a and it told me int type. But when I pass it into cv2.line function like below. Both are same? but I had a different result!

Any suggestion?

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)
a=int(img.shape[1])-1 #result =511
b=int(img.shape[2])-1 #result =511
print type(a)
print a
#a=511 this is test value
#b=511 this is test value
print type(a)
cv2.line(img,(0,0),(a,b),(0,0,255),5) #red line
cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)#blue line
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

See picture below

[image: image Error]

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem.

Comment: i just imported new picture, pls see

Comment: Consider accepting the answer since it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`shape[2]` is the number of channels, not the width as you expect.

change

```
a=int(img.shape[1])-1
b=int(img.shape[2])-1
```

to

```
a=int(img.shape[0])-1
b=int(img.shape[1])-1
```